# SQL Execution tooks too long

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, long-integer

I'm currently working on a project that needs a "Similar Series" Panel. I have a Table for the series and one of their genres. Need to select movies with least 4 genres in common with the selected movie.

I came up with this query:

```
SELECT s_id,stitle,sdesc FROM s_genre 
INNER JOIN series ON s_genre.s_id=series.id 
WHERE s_id IN (
    SELECT s_id FROM s_genre 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT g_id FROM s_genre WHERE s_id = $mid) a USING (g_id) 
    GROUP BY s_id HAVING COUNT(s_id)>3
) AND s_id != $mid 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5
```

It works, but it takes almost 20 seconds to load :(

Any ideas how I can reduce the loading time? Any suggestions are appreciated :)

## Thanks in advance.

Looks like the problem is cause by "ORDER BY RAND()" ... removing it would reduce the loading time to 0.5s

Comment: Try removing your `ORDER BY RAND()` and see what the time taken is then. `RAND()` has to be evaluated for every row, and is not a particularly fast operation, then you're sorting by something that's not indexed, which is slow too, end result is it can be very costly.

Comment: Also, do you have DB indices on the `id` columns (i.e the `s_genre.s_id` column and the `series.id` column)?

Comment: but i need it to select random series, if not the result would always be the same. without rand, it took 0.5 seconds to load :)

Comment: how do you connect to db ? `mysqli` or may `pdo` ... ?!?!?

Comment: i connect to DB using mysqli , yes

Comment: do you use localhost as host or 127.0.0.1 ? if you use localhost, try 127.0.0.1 and than check performance... in pdo it's a big difference

Comment: just shuffle your result with php

Comment: no, i don't use localhost ... problem mostly is because of "ORDER BY RAND()" but unfortunately i need it, is there any work arounds for it?

Comment: shuffle? you mean give it random s_id and make it select from it? then what about the genre selection? it would even end up not selecting nothing :(

Comment: just like Fabricator sayed. do the rand with php. select your stuff and **[SHUFFLE](http://php.net//manual/en/function.shuffle.php)** it in php

Comment: guess I'd try that out, will inform you all about the results soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ORDER BY rand() seems to be the major problem, it might be worth recoding the query to do a join against the sub query:-

```
SELECT s_genre.s_id,
        series.stitle,
        series.sdesc 
FROM s_genre 
INNER JOIN series ON s_genre.s_id = series.id 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.s_id 
    FROM s_genre a
    INNER JOIN s_genre b
    ON a.g_id = b.g_id
    WHERE b.s_id = $mid
    GROUP BY a.s_id 
    HAVING COUNT(a.s_id) > 3
) sub0
ON s_genre.s_id = sub0.s_id
WHERE s_genre.s_id != $mid 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5
```

There are techniques to select random records, but doing so with this query could be a bit messy. Most rely on having a fairly evenly distributed unique identifier for the rows, and (while I assume s_genre.s_id is a unique id) the query will have generated holes in the range of these and they will doubtless have holes in the range.

Comment: sounds like a good approach but , unfortunately returns the following error : Column 's_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Fixed that, but unable to test it (adding table declares and a little sample data to the question makes this far easier to do).